# Celery worker-offline event not generated

Tags: python, celery

I am trying to capture the worker-related events, but there is something weird going on in my application: all the task events are being generated and captured and the worker events as well, except for worker-offline event. Is there any specific setting that I need to make for this event to be generated?
I am using Celery 3.0.23

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research, I ended up answering my own question: it was a bug which has been fixed in the later versions of celery.